# Access (ADO) query between two hour ranges

Tags: sql, ms-access, adodb

Using VB to query an access .mdb database via ADODB.

My date column holds both date and time, I would like to to build a query which will ignore the date, and refer only to the time in that column, in such a way, that will enable me to return records that have their time in between a range given by the user, ignoring the date.

[image: For Example]

I tried selecting between numbers, but I believe access I'm doing it wrong

```
...WHERE [Date_Time_Of_Birth] Between #04:00:00# and #06:00:00#
```

Just doesn't work as intended ... need a direction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [TimeValue Function](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/TimeValue-Function-35d775cc-c6c7-49bb-8202-e338ac930e23) to ignore the date portion of your *Date_Time_Of_Birth* values.

Also *#04:00:00#* and *#06:00:00#* are 4 and 6 AM. Since you want PM times, write the values as in one of these examples:

```sql
WHERE TimeValue([Date_Time_Of_Birth]) Between #16:00:00# and #18:00:00#

WHERE TimeValue([Date_Time_Of_Birth]) Between #4 PM# and #6 PM#
```