# Form field empty in PHP search

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, prepared-statement

I have a html form with textbox and combobox.

- If I write something on textbox, the search is filtered.
- If I write something on textbox and select an item on combobox, the
  search is filtered.
- If I leave empty the textbox and combobox, the search takes me all results.

But,

- If I leave empty the textbox and select an item on combobox, the search  takes me all results (and not just selected item of combobox)

I would like it, if all element are empty, the search return all the results. But if the tetxbox is empty and the others are selected, bring me back not all results.

**index.html** (only `<form>`)

```
<form action="index.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="input" placeholder="Ricerca Ordini"> <br><br>
<label for="selectmenu">Tipo:</label>
<select id="selectmenu" name="tipo">
    <option>C1</option>
    <option>CR</option>
    <option>F1</option>
    <option>FP</option>
    <option>FPE</option>
    <option selected="selected">All Type</option>
</select>
<label for="spinner">ID:</label>
<input id="spinner" name="id"> <br><br>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to"> <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="search">
</form>
```

**index.php** (only important part)

```
<?php
define ('DBNAME',"./DinamicoWeb.mdb"); // Definisce il nome del database
define ('DBTBL',"Ordini"); // Definisce il nome della tabella
define ('PKNAME',"Id Ord"); // Definisce il nome della chiave primaria
define ('PKCOL',0); // Definisce la posizione della chiave primaria
define ('LINKPK',true); // Abilita i link alla PK per modifica-cancella

$con = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$conStr = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=".
            realpath(DBNAME).";";
$con->open($conStr);

$input=$_POST['input'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
$tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
$numero=$_POST['numero'];


$sql="SELECT [Id Ord] AS [ID], [Tipo Ord] AS [Tipo], [N Ord] AS [Numero], [Data Ord] AS [Data], [Ragione Sociale], [Indirizzo], [TotImp] AS [IMPORTO TOTALE], [TotIva] AS [IMPORTO IVA] FROM [Ordini] WHERE [Indirizzo] LIKE '%$input%' OR [Ragione Sociale] LIKE '%$input%' OR [Id Ord] LIKE '$id' OR [Tipo Ord] LIKE '$tipo' OR [N Ord] LIKE '$numero'";

$rs = $con->execute($sql);


if($rs === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $con->ErrorMsg(), E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
  $rows_returned = $rs->RecordCount();
}

$numFields = $rs->Fields->count;

// Print Table...
```

**Snippet of Index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ricerca Ordini</title>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
      from = $( "#from" )
        .datepicker({
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          numberOfMonths: 1
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
      to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1
      })
      .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
      });
 
    function getDate( element ) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
      } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
      }
 
      return date;
    }
  } );
  </script>
 <style>
 body{
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  margin: 50px;
 }
 .demoHeaders {
  margin-top: 2em;
 }
 #dialog-link {
  padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
 }
 #dialog-link span.ui-icon {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: .2em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -8px;
 }
 #icons {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #icons li {
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
 }
 #icons span.ui-icon {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 4px;
 }
 .fakewindowcontain .ui-widget-overlay {
  position: absolute;
 }
 select {
  width: 200px;
 }
 </style>
 
</head>

<body>
<h1>Ricerca Ordini</h1>
<form action="index.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="input" placeholder="Ricerca Ordini"> <br><br>
<label for="selectmenu">Tipo:</label>
<select id="selectmenu" name="tipo">
 <option>C1</option>
 <option>CR</option>
 <option>F1</option>
 <option>FP</option>
 <option>FPE</option>
 <option selected="selected">All Type</option>
</select>
<label for="spinner">ID:</label>
<input id="spinner" name="id"> <br><br>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to"> <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="search">
</form>

<script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

$( "#accordion" ).accordion();



var availableTags = [
 "ActionScript",
 "AppleScript",
 "Asp",
 "BASIC",
 "C",
 "C++",
 "Clojure",
 "COBOL",
 "ColdFusion",
 "Erlang",
 "Fortran",
 "Groovy",
 "Haskell",
 "Java",
 "JavaScript",
 "Lisp",
 "Perl",
 "PHP",
 "Python",
 "Ruby",
 "Scala",
 "Scheme"
];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
 source: availableTags
});



$( "#button" ).button();
$( "#button-icon" ).button({
 icon: "ui-icon-gear",
 showLabel: false
});



$( "#radioset" ).buttonset();



$( "#controlgroup" ).controlgroup();



$( "#tabs" ).tabs();



$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 width: 400,
 buttons: [
  {
   text: "Ok",
   click: function() {
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
   }
  },
  {
   text: "Cancel",
   click: function() {
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
   }
  }
 ]
});

// Link to open the dialog
$( "#dialog-link" ).click(function( event ) {
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
 event.preventDefault();
});



$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
 inline: true
});



$( "#slider" ).slider({
 range: true,
 values: [ 17, 67 ]
});



$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
 value: 20
});



$( "#spinner" ).spinner();



$( "#menu" ).menu();



$( "#tooltip" ).tooltip();



$( "#selectmenu" ).selectmenu();


// Hover states on the static widgets
$( "#dialog-link, #icons li" ).hover(
 function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-hover" );
 },
 function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-hover" );
 }
);
</script>
</body>
</html>﻿
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `$input` is an empty string

```
WHERE [Indirizzo] LIKE '%$input%' OR [Ragione Sociale] LIKE '%$input%'
```

means "I want select all the rows". So, first check if it's empty, and if it's not keep that from the criteria, otherwise remove them.

```
if (empty($input)) {
    // query without [Indirizzo] LIKE '%$input%' OR [Ragione Sociale] LIKE '%$input%'
} else {
    // query with [Indirizzo] LIKE '%$input%' OR [Ragione Sociale] LIKE '%$input%'
}
```

Comment: Great! This work! And an other little question. I have two input text (from, to). How can I write on SQL (between?)? :D

Comment: That's worth writing  another question. But, before that, you should google "adodb sql between two dates" (first result: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29569087/711206)

Comment: Yes, I know. I already try the principal option, but doesn't work. (`TimeValue([Data Ord]) Between '$data1' AND '$data2'`)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can check the value for blank as follows:

```
if(!strlen($_POST['search']) || $_POST['search'] == ''){
 //use query without where clause
}else{
 //use query with where clause
}
```

Comment: I have to insert `$_POST['search']` or `$_POST['input']`?